# Деплой телеграм бота на Яндекс.Облаке

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, deploy, yandex-cloud

Жил-был на Heroku телеграм бот на питоне. Всё хорошо работало. Использовал python-telegram-bot и вебхуки.
Но т.к. Heroku закрывает ботов на бесплатных тарифах, решил мигрировать на Yandex.Cloud.
И вот тут у меня ничего не получается. Саму среду в яндексе настроить удалось, простой эхо бот работает. А вот как связать получаемый от телеграма json с `Updater` из python-telegram-bot пока не понимаю.
Короче, вопрос: как настроить бота на python-telegram-bot в Яндекс.Облако?

Comment: В общем так и не разобрался. Пришлось разбирать приходящий от телеграма json вручную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите это видео. [serverless yandex.cloud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VRSKlMzOX4)Сегодня по нему бота в облако переселил...только вот засыпает пока что быстро...копаюсь дальше

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Да, полезное видео, получил ответы на свои вопросы. @Серый, спасибо

Comment: @bruno13 Рад был помочь. После заливания бота в яндекс облако, вам дается грант на 4000 руб., не забудьте его отключить после пробного периода, иначе начнутся списывания денег с карточки, которую вы укажете при регистрации...А бот засыпал, потому что webhook забывал запускать, а запускал его через тестирование))